# How to show graph of nodes/relationships in Neo4j Browser

Tags: neo4j

Basic question: I've figured out how to use the Neo4j Desktop/Browser to run some of the sample graphGists code. However, I can't figure out how to see the database graphcically (circles for nodes, lines for connections) within the Browser. Is this even possible to do? If so, tips much appreciated.

I'm using a Linux laptop.

Thanks!

Kurt

Comment: You need to issue a query that returns nodes and relationships, or paths. You might want to take a look at the Movies graph for examples (use `:play movies`) in the browser

Answer (score 8):

To answer your question - yes it's possible to visualize the entire database:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

1. Try the query on a different browser.
2. If the problem persists, try to isolate the issue by trying a node-only query e.g. MATCH (node) RETURN node LIMIT 10
3. Try limiting the results of your query to 300 and check if the graph works.

Please share your query, it may be a cypher issue.

Note: Wanted to leave a comment, don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.schema.visualization()
```

Answer (score 0):

By default there is a web browser if you go to port 7474 of your server IP or http://localhost:7474 in case of default installation

If you want to write your own version of the same (why?) Take up any JS graph library and you can achieve similar visuals in result

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I think the issue is more query based.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I think the issue is more query based. I ran the commands in from sample code in a Help example, I created nodes and relationships for the movie Matrix. When I ran the code, I found that the "Graph" option in the left bar appears as shown in the link below. I don't get that icon (or the stuff to its right) when I experiment with the graphGists. Any ideas what's going on? Thanks again!

https://photos.app.goo.gl/VRJnbYCor1DQGohu8